# is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm making a memory cache simulation on C++ and after a lot of coding im getting this error:

```
g++ main.cpp blocoMemoria.cpp endereco.cpp instrucao.cpp mmu.cpp maquina.cpp -o joubert.o -g -Wall

main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:

main.cpp:18:29: warning: ‘ram’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
BlocoMemoria *ram = gerarBM(ram, tamanhoRam);
                  ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:19:32: warning: ‘cache1’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
BlocoMemoria *cache1 = gerarBM(cache1, tamanhoCache1);
                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:20:32: warning: ‘cache2’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
BlocoMemoria *cache2 = gerarBM(cache2, tamanhoCache2);
                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:26:66: warning: ‘memoriaInstrucoes’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Instrucao *memoriaInstrucoes = montarInstrucoesProgramaAleatorio(memoriaInstrucoes, tamanhoPrograma, qdePalavrasBloco, tamanhoRam);
```

This is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include "endereco.hpp"
#include "instrucao.hpp"
#include "blocoMemoria.hpp"
#include "mmu.hpp"
#include "maquina.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int tamanhoRam= 1000;
    int tamanhoCache1 = 8;
    int tamanhoCache2 = 16;
    int tamanhoPrograma = 1000;
    int qdePalavrasBloco = 4;

    BlocoMemoria *ram = gerarBM(ram, tamanhoRam);
    BlocoMemoria *cache1 = gerarBM(cache1, tamanhoCache1);
    BlocoMemoria *cache2 = gerarBM(cache2, tamanhoCache2);

    montarRam(ram, tamanhoRam, qdePalavrasBloco);
    montarCacheVazia(tamanhoCache1, cache1);
    montarCacheVazia(tamanhoCache2, cache2);

    Instrucao *memoriaInstrucoes = montarInstrucoesProgramaAleatorio(memoriaInstrucoes, tamanhoPrograma, qdePalavrasBloco, tamanhoRam);

    maquina(memoriaInstrucoes, ram, cache1, cache2);
    deleteBM(cache2);
    deleteBM(cache1);
    deleteBM(ram);
    deleteInst(memoriaInstrucoes);
    cout<<"terminou\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This is my blocoMemoria.cpp:

```
#include "blocoMemoria.hpp"
using namespace std;
struct blocoMemoria{
        int *palavras = new int[4];
        int endBloco = -1;
        bool atualizado = false;
        int custo = 0;
        int cacheHit = 0;
};

BlocoMemoria* gerarBM(BlocoMemoria* b, int q){
    b=new BlocoMemoria[q];
    return b;
}
BlocoMemoria *posToPoint(BlocoMemoria *z, int k){
    BlocoMemoria *aux=&z[k];
    return aux;
}

void deleteBM(BlocoMemoria *a){
    delete a;
}

void juntarBM(BlocoMemoria *a, BlocoMemoria *b, int i){
    if(i==1){
        setPalavras(a, getPalavras(b));
        setEndBloco(a, getEndBloco(b));
        setAtualizado(a, isAtualizado(b));
        setCusto(a, getCusto(b));
        setCacheHit(a, getCacheHit(b));
    }

    else{
        setPalavras(&a[i], getPalavras(b));
        setEndBloco(&a[i], getEndBloco(b));
        setAtualizado(&a[i], isAtualizado(b));
        setCusto(&a[i], getCusto(b));
        setCacheHit(&a[i], getCacheHit(b));
    }
}

int getCusto(BlocoMemoria *c) {
    return c->custo;
}

void setCusto(BlocoMemoria *c, int custo) {
    c->custo = custo;
}

int* getPalavras(BlocoMemoria *c) {
        return c->palavras;
}

int* getPalavras(BlocoMemoria *c, int i) {
        return c[i].palavras;
}

void setPalavras(BlocoMemoria* c,int *palavras) {
    c->palavras = palavras;
}

int getEndBloco(BlocoMemoria *c) {
    return c->endBloco;
}

void setEndBloco(BlocoMemoria *c, int endBloco) {
    c->endBloco = endBloco;
}

bool isAtualizado(BlocoMemoria *c) {
    return c->atualizado;
}

void setAtualizado(BlocoMemoria *c) {
    c->atualizado = !c->atualizado;
}
void setAtualizado(BlocoMemoria *c, bool d) {
    c->atualizado = d;
}

int getCacheHit(BlocoMemoria *c) {
    return c->cacheHit;
}

void setCacheHit(BlocoMemoria *c, int cacheHit) {
    c->cacheHit = cacheHit;
}
```

I'm a bit of a noob so i have no idea why this is happening if i'm returning the right pointer at:

```
BlocoMemoria* gerarBM()
```

I tried just declaring them in the main as
    BlocoMemoria*ram=new BlocoMemoria[];
but the compiler doesn't like that very much.

the reason i need this fixed is because there arent any operations being made in the main program execution.

it does compile without the -Wall

been doing this for hours and am getting kind of desperate and dont know if im even giving the necessary info, if  you need anything just let me know and ill edit this, thanks.

Comment: Another issue with this code, beyond the one I show in my answer, is that `deleteBM` uses the standard (scalar) `delete` instead of the array `delete[]`.

It should be `delete[] a`, since you are generating these with the syntax `new T[n]`

Comment: damn dude, youre my hero, didnt see that at all

Answer (score 1):

This line is the problem:

```cpp
BlocoMemoria *ram = gerarBM(ram, tamanhoRam);
```

You are using `ram` on the right side in the same statement where you're defining it.

Instead, you could change `gerarBM` like this:

```cpp
BlocoMemoria* gerarBM(int q){
    return new BlocoMemoria[q];
}
```

and call it like:

```
BlocoMemoria* ram = gerarBM(tamanhoRam);
```

Comment: just made the change and it spat out some different errors, im gonna work on them and see if it works now. tbh after you said it i felt kinda stupid cuz it seems so obvious now, thanks a lot.